Sorting by Custom Array
I'm trying to sort a Google Sheet (sample) by where one column's data ('Leads and Onboarding'!D7:D', the column heading "STATUS") falls within a custom array ("lead_status_sort!B5:B"). In this case, I want Partnerships first, then Onboardings, then Connectings, then Leads, then Abandoneds.
I've tried to write a bound Google App Script to do that. Here's the entire function (question continues below).
function sortLeads() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // gets bound spreadsheet
  var sheet = ss.getSheetById("547710831"); // gets leads sheet

  console.log("Getting List...");
  var list = ss.getSheetById("1696685410").getRange("B5:B").getValues().filter(String).flat(); // gets the list in lead_status_sort
  console.log(list); 
  list = list.reverse(); // We reverse the list, because we're going to iterate through the sheet moving matching rows to the top

  var firstRow = ss.getSheetById("1940886045").getRange("B6").getValue(); // This gets the row immediately following the row with "ORG" in the B column. 
  var rowCount = ss.getSheetById("1940886045").getRange("B7").getValue(); // This gets the number of rows with organizations in them
  var lastRow = firstRow + rowCount - 1; // This is the last row with an organization
  console.log("Sorting Leads Sheet Rows " + firstRow + " to " + lastRow)  
  var statusList = sheet.getRange("D" + firstRow + ":D" + lastRow).getValues().flat(); // gets the array of statuses

  for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    console.log("Checking Array for Status = " + list[i]);
    for (let j = 0; j < rowCount; j++) {
      console.log("    Checking Row " + (firstRow + j));
      if (statusList[j] == list[i]) {
        console.log("    True");
        var rowSpec = sheet.getRange("A" + (firstRow + j) + ":" + (firstRow + j));
        try {
          console.log("    Moving Row");
          sheet.moveRows(rowSpec, firstRow);
          // LOCATION A
        } catch (error){
          
        }
      } else {
        console.log("    False");
      }
    }
  }
  console.log("pause");
  Utilities.sleep(5000);
}


It seems to make sense. In fact, if you manually change the i values, for example,
for (let i = 1; i < 2; i++) {

... and so on, it works great! The problem is, when I allow it to iterate through the entire for-loop, I've realized that it doesn't actually move the rows when the script reaches LOCATION A (see the middle of the for-loop section). It moves the rows at the end of the script. (I wrote in a pause to be sure.)
So, the script is queuing actions that it then executes at script-end. And, it doesn't seem to execute them in order (or, it tries to, but Google Sheets doesn't move fast enough to do it in the order the script reads them).
How do I solve this problem? Am I going about it in entirely the wrong way?

Would you be able to provide sample markdown tables with your input and your expected output so that the community may further help you. The spreadsheet you provided does not allow copying the data which makes it difficult for the community to copy your data and replicate your issue. You may create the markdown tables with the help of this link.

Tried SpreadsheetApp.flush()? PS: FWIW, Do the sort inplace within javascript within the array with Array.sort and then setValues

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Thanks so much everyone! @doubleunary answered this brilliantly, but I'll be sure to set permissions for my sample differently in the future.

The easiest way to organize that data would be to use a Group by  view. That won't show the data in the custom order described in the question though.
You can implement a custom sort order with a plain vanilla spreadsheet formula without resorting to scripting. The formula adds a numeric column that acts as the sort key, and you use the new column to sort the sheet to the custom order you wanted.
Put this formula in cell M6:
=vstack( 
  "Sort key", 
  arrayformula(ifna(match( 
    D7:D, 
    vstack("Partnership", "Onboarding", "Connecting", "Lead", "Abandoned"), 
    0 
  ))) 
)

Then click cell M6 and choose Data > Sort sheet > Sort Sheet A to Z.
The same can be done in Apps Script, although there seems to be little point doing so. Get the data range with Sheet.getrange(), get the data with Range.getValues(), sort the data with Array.sort() with a custom compareFunction, and finally put the sorted data back with Range.setValues(), like this:
function sortLeads() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Leads and Onboarding');
  const statusRange = sheet.getRange(`A${sheet.getFrozenRows() + 1}:L`);
  const data = statusRange.getValues().filter(row => row.join(''));
  const _index = v => ['Partnership', 'Onboarding', 'Connecting', 'Lead', 'Abandoned'].indexOf(v);
  data.sort((a, b) => _index(a) < _index(b) ? -1 : _index(a) > _index(b) ? 1 : 0);
  statusRange.setValues(data);
}

Cannot test that because the sample spreadsheet is set to prevent copying.

This is a beautiful bit of spreadsheeting. Writing it to an array so that they can add rows later without trouble, using the match function with the nested VSTACK so that you're returning the numbers, and then sorting accordingly. It's perfect. Excellently done, sir/ma'am! I'll also check on this App Script code. I know that my use-case doesn't need it any longer (as you mentioned), but it never hurts to understand it better! Thanks again!
